# Image width not being rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have an image tag whose `src` attribute is initially blank (`src=""`). On calling an API, a url is returned which is the public url of the image.

After this URL is returned by the api, it is set on the `src` attribute (`src="protocol://public/url/of/the/image"`)

My problem is that the image must be exactly 48px X 48px (they must appear to be thumbnail images). If the image is larger than that then, it must be reduced to those dimensions and if it is smaller than that then it must stretch to those dimensions.

I tried setting the height and width properties and/or the height and width through css (external stylesheet as well as inline styling).

There are 4 such `<img>` tags. Not all the images render with the specified height and width, the image(s) not rendering properly with the height and with are not specific images but quite random.

I hope I have described the problem adequately.
Thank you

**Edit 1**: My code
Markup

```
<div class="some-container" id="first-one"> <img src='' class="thumbs"/> </div>
<div class="some-container" id="second-one"> <img src='' class="thumbs"/> </div>
<div class="some-container" id="third-one"> <img src='' class="thumbs"/> </div>
<div class="some-container" id="fourth-one"> <img src='' class="thumbs"/> </div>
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
 // call to the api which returns the urls as an array
 success: function(data){
     // Assume data['url*'] gives the url
     $('#first-one').attr('src', data['url1']);
     $('#second-one').attr('src', data['url2']);
     $('#third-one').attr('src', data['url3']);
     $('#fourth-one').attr('src', data['url1']);
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.thumbs{
    height: '48px';
    width: '48px';
}
```

When I inspect I see that the url has been set properly and the correct image is also rendered however the size is what is inaccurate.
As mentioned I have also tried setting the styles inline, and using the height and width properties but to no avail.

**Edit 2**: The Demo:

http://new.fundinghunt.co/x-ai-raises-23-million-for-its-ai-personal-assistant-plans-to-launch-this-fall/

Once the page loads, scroll down you will see a widget with a few emoji click 'Love' (otherwise the section I am talking about will not show up).

**Edit 3**: The Solution:

The problem has finally been resolved as [chsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669624/chsdk)

pointed out I had to add a `display: inline-block;` to the links. Additionally I had to wrap the `<img>` tag and the link in separate `<div>..</div>` tags. This resolved the issue.

Thank you for your help everyone :)

Comment: You described the problem, but your actual code is missing.

Comment: @chsdk Sure I have just updated my question

Comment: But you don't want us only to click on the 'Love' button, do you? :-)

Comment: @Joachim Haha no that is not the motive. But the problem occurs only when more than one image is loaded, and clicking Love right now is the only way all of them will show up (1-4) links show up depending on what you click and what others have clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in `CSS` properties value doesn't need quotes, So just replace:

```
.thumbs{
   height: '48px';
   width: '48px';
}
```

With the following:

```
.thumbs{
   height: 48px;
   width: 48px;
}
```

Otherwise they won't be considered as valid `CSS`, and that's your problem.

**This is a working snippet:**

```css
    .thumbs {
      height: 48px;
      width: 48px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="some-container" id="first-one">
  <img src='' class="thumbs" />
</div>
<div class="some-container" id="second-one">
  <img src='' class="thumbs" />
</div>
<div class="some-container" id="third-one">
  <img src='' class="thumbs" />
</div>
<div class="some-container" id="fourth-one">
  <img src='' class="thumbs" />
</div>
```

Comment: Well more of the images are rendering properly now but still not all. I have posted a link to the demo and also updated my codebase for it incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: Well, in fact in the page you shared you are givin an inline style to all the images, expect the "Love" one, just give them a class and apply it to all the images.

Comment: As you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/1zdqe9o5/4/ setting the size via a class doesn't work for images whose 'src' attribute is set later.

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Really !!! `img, .image {
  width: 48;
  height: 48;
}
`, using values without units in css? [**This is an updated fiddle with valid CSS**](https://jsfiddle.net/1zdqe9o5/6/), in fact you have to use a unit `48px`.

Comment: @chsdk I am not talking about the emoji, after you click the others are supposed to reduce in size. If you see below that section there is one entitled "don't miss the following stories from this website" that has links to related articles based on what you clicked, which is where the thumbnails I am talking about are .
PS: you will not need to click anything now just reload the page the section will appear.

Comment: @AkshayPardhanani It seems like, a loading problem, try to give the links a `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: @chsdk Thank you that suggestion has helped me make some progress on this. However the images still do not size up properly, but if I right click on the link then the thumbnail quickly resizes to the expected dimensions. This is a really strange problem I have run into...

Comment: Yes, as I told you I think it's a loadig problem, it's really weird, and seems really hard to follow but just try to inspect it and debug, surely you will find a way.

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher, it's fine. :)